# Spring 4 + JPA (Hibernate 4) + JTA transaction manager doesn't flush automatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am migrating an application from

Spring 3.0.5 + JPA 2.0
to
Spring 4 + JPA (Hibernate 4)

I have followed the migration guide : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework.

The application is using a JTA transaction manager : a Jencks / GeronimoPlatformTransactionManager (because of transactions distributed on datasources and ESB).

The Spring / JPA configuration is :

```
<bean id="rduEntityManagerFactory" class="ch.vd.dsas.rdu.repository.crud.service.ExtendedLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    depends-on="rduTransactionManagerLocator,jGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactoryLocator">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="rduPersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${rdu.jpa.database}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <bean class="ch.vd.dsas.rdu.commons.tx.spring.JtaPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
            <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="rduDataSource" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="jpaProperties"/>
</bean>

<util:properties id="jpaProperties">
    <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">JTA</prop>
    <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">CALLBACK</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${rdu.jpa.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
    <!-- Transaction properties -->
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">ch.vd.dsas.rdu.ref.transaction.jencks.JencksTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">ch.vd.dsas.rdu.transaction.jencks.JencksTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${rdu.datasource.schemaMetier}</prop>
    <!-- Debug properties -->
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
    <!-- Cache properties -->
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.ReplicatedSingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.cluster_name">${rdu.hibernate.cache.jgroups.cluster.name}</prop>
    <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/hibernate-ehcache.xml</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Transactions are annotation driven :

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="rduJtaTransactionManager" />
```

The transaction manager is declared like that :

```
<!-- From Jencks org.jencks:jencks:2.2 -->
<bean id="rduJencksTransactionManager" class="org.jencks.factory.TransactionManagerFactoryBean" />

<bean id="rduJtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <qualifier value="rdu" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="rduJencksTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="rduJencksTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="rduTransactionManagerLocator" class="ch.vd.dsas.rdu.transaction.jencks.TransactionManagerLocator" factory-method="getInstance">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="rduJencksTransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

The application is starting and accessing data and displaying it.

However no insert / update are performed.

If I change data and submit the change the application receives the change but the data does not get flushed to the database.

I have activated logs and I see the transaction :

> rdu 2015-06-18 20:28:01,817 [    http-8080-1] DEBUG [                     o.s.t.j.JtaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'rdu'
>   rdu 2015-06-18 20:28:01,817 [    http-8080-1] DEBUG [                     o.s.t.j.JtaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction
>   rdu 2015-06-18 20:28:01,823 [    http-8080-1] DEBUG [                     o.s.t.j.JtaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit

But nothing is sent to the database.

If I intercept the execution through debugging and manually flush the Hibernate session, the data gets updated.

It seems the JPA / Hibernate session is not coordinated with the transaction.

I can't figure out what is missing in the configuration and why the  session is not flushed automatically.

Hope you can help me with this issue.

Best regards,
Eric

Comment: I hope this could help http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/117081-session-not-flushed-with-hibernate-4-1-3-jta-and-spring-transaction-management-integ

Comment: Thanks Amogh :-). I'm going to try one of these solutions.  I'm wondering if I should not switch the transaction manager to Bitronix like this [link](https://github.com/edwinkun/xadatasource-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-datasource.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to this property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">ch.vd.dsas.rdu.ref.transaction.jencks.JencksTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
```

The `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` property is not the same with `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class` and it should point to an [AbstractJtaPlatform](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/internal/AbstractJtaPlatform.html) implementation:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
```

Comment: You are right, I just discovered the same this morning. The package name is wrong. After fixing it, the application is flushing the changes to the database :-) !